# What's a more Pythonic way to test parts of my code?

Tags: python, windows, testing

I'm on Windows 10, Python 2.7.13 installed via Anaconda. Recently I've been writing a lot of scripts to read/write data from files to other files, move them around, and do some visualizations with matplotlib. My workflow has been having an Anaconda Prompt open next to Sublime Text, and I copy/paste individual lines into my workspace to test something. This doesn't feel like a "best practice", especially because I can't copy/paste multiple lines with indents, so I have to write them out manually twice. I'd really like to find a better way to work on this. What would you recommend changing?

Comment: Are you not using an IDE? What are you writing code in? Anaconda comes with Spyder.

Comment: Anaconda prompt isn't designed to develop code. You've been torturing yourself! Open Spyder and work in that. It has an interactive console for checking out variables in your script or testing things out. It's a bit hard to describe c.f. what you're coming from. There are other IDEs and I don't intend to get into comparisons but Spyder should already be available.

Comment: I usually do functional testing in Jupyter Notebooks. That allows you to get a cell working, then another, then another, re-running each piece as needed, then at the end you can export the whole thing as a .py file

Comment: Also note that Python 2.7 reaches its end of life in 2020 so it's a good idea to move to Python 3

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of software testing that vary in their complexity and what they test. Generally speaking, it is a good practice to leverage what is know as unit testing. Unit testing is the methodology of writing groups of tests where each test is responsible for testing a small "unit" of code. By only testing individual pieces of your project with each test, you are given a very granular idea of what parts of your project is working correctly and what parts are not working correctly. It also allows for your tests to be repeatable, source controlled, and automated. Typically each "unit" that a test is written for is a single callable item such as a function or method of a class.

In order to get the most out of unit testing, your functions and methods need to be single responsibility entities. This means they should perform one task and one task only. This makes it much easier to test them. Python's standard library has a built package, appropriately named [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) to perform this type of testing..

I would start looking at the unittest package's documentation. It provides more explanation on unit testing and how to use the package in your python code. You can also use the [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/) package to determine how much of you code is tested via unit tests.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know if I was at the point where I needed to start learning to do unit testing, but it seems like a good skill to have.